# Does aeron support "ReadIndex Read" and "Lease Read"?

Tags: aeron

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4pct.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1vsC.png)

If we have a lot of read request, so use raft log to implements read will cause disk space increase quilk.
so, does aeron cluster have any solutions?

thanks your help